# Capture a dynamic value generated for request.1 and pass it to another request

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to pass a URL with a specific parameter having dynamic value for eg. email value will be

```
 ${__Random(0000,9999)}+$tester@testing.com.
```

This generate a random value+email id and get passed for request no.1.

I want to get that exact value for the email id parameter which get passed for that request and again pass that value to another request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use third parameter in [__Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) to save random value:

> A reference name for reusing the value computed by this function.

```
${__Random(0000,9999, rnd)}+$tester@testing.com
```

And then use the variable concatenated with email suffix later:

```
${rnd}+$tester@testing.com
```

Comment: Given the respective values for query_1 is 'x' and query_2 is 'y' in http://request 1 . I am refering a third parameter 'abc'  in ${__V(query_${__Random(1,2, abc)})} and then am using the variable 'abc' in the next request http://request 2 (assuming that it will fetch either x or y randomly) but it is fetching values 1 or 2 randomly. Can someone help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @hikarthiks in second request use `${__V(query_${abc})}`